# awk regular expression doesn't work

Tags: regex, awk, gawk

I want to check if the contents match a pattern.
here is my code to check at least 3 consecutive digits.

```
echo "356979703" | awk '/[0-9]{3}/{print $1}'
```

But awk doesn't print out the line, why? where did I go wrong?

Comment: For me it actually does work. Can you try on a different machine?

Comment: @JeroenPeeters  I am using RedHat 5.8 Tikanga, it wont' work

Comment: `echo "356979703" | awk --re-interval '/[0-9]{3}/{print $1}'  `

Comment: It seems [it works here](https://ideone.com/FDOrBT).

Comment: You're using an awk that doesn't support RE intervals [by default].